# AWS athena resultset showing values zig zaged values for columns

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-crawler, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I'm running a custom crawler in Aws to fetch the data from Data source and placing them in AWS Data Catalogue tables.
After the crawler finishes its run and I query the table in Athena. I can see that the values which should be coming under one column and moving to the next column in the resultset. Is this the issue with Crawler which I'm running or the problem with Athena console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that your columns are swapped is that there is a mismatch between the metadata and the underlying source-data. This is because the crawler observes more or fewer columns than it expects. Check if this is the case.

To clarify, a crawler does not move data but rather scans it to see what data types are there including columns/types. The results in metadata which describes the data that exists in the data-source. Athena can then use this metadata to query data from the source.